# Is it safe to use hooks in createSelector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, reselect

I have just found out that I can use data hooks in `createSelector` functions and it works. An example:

```
// This is a normal hook
const useUserReducer = () => {
  const userAccessData = useSelector(state => state?.userAccessData)
  return userAccessData
}

// Here I use the hook as first argument!
export const useUserReducerFromCreateSelector = createSelector(useUserReducer, (result) => {
  console.log(result) // userAccessData printed correctly
  return result
})
```

Then I use it in my component as a normal hook:

```
const Component = () => {
  const result = useUserReducerFromCreateSelector([])
  console.log(result) // userAccessData printed correctly
  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(result)}
    </>
  )
}
```

I dont see any documentation about this, so I wonder if its safe to use it. It would help me a lot creating reusable selectors.

(I tested while changing the state at various points in time and I always see the correct state)

Comment: By "it works" you mean you tested while changing the state at various points in time and you always see the correct state or do you mean "I don't get an error" ?

Comment: I tested while changing the state at various points in time and I always see the correct state. I update the question.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly an abuse if it is working. `createSelector` is only supposed to be a pure state selector function, so naming the returned selector function like a React hook, i.e. `useUserReducerFromCreateSelector`, is likely to cause some linter warnings eventually.

The potential issue is that Reselect and `createSelector` creates memoized selector functions. If the input value to a selector doesn't change, then the selector function returns the previously computed selector value. This means that a selector using a React hook like this potentially conditionally calling a React hook which is a violation of the Rules of Hooks.

> ### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls. (If you’re curious,
> we’ll explain this in depth below.)
>
> ### Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> `Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.` Instead, you
> can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).
>
> By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a
> component is clearly visible from its source code.

I don't consider it safe to use any React hook in a selector function like this.

Split out the logic of selecting the state from the `useUserReducerFromCreateSelector` hook to be used in your selector functions.

Example:

```
const userAccessData = state => state?.userAccessData || {};

const computedUserAccessData = createSelector(
  [userAccessData],
  data => {
    // logic to compute derived state, etc...
    return newUserAccessData;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was really intrigued [seeing this particular use](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1401) in the `redux-toolkit` github repo issues and nobody complaining about it so I decided to ask the same question in the `reselect` github page.

[Here](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/issues/577) is the response of Mark Erikson (redux maintainer):

> No, this is not safe!
>
> You're technically getting away with it because of how you're using
> that in a component. But if you were to try to use that selector
> outside of a component, it would break.
>
> I'd really recommend sticking with keeping these concepts separate.
> Write and name selectors as selectors. Write and name hooks as hooks.
> Don't try and mix the two :)
>
> To be clear, the code that you wrote above should run. It's ultimately
> "just" composition of functions and calling them in a particular
> order.
>
> But given how hooks work, and how selectors work, it's best to keep
> those concepts separate when writing the code to avoid confusion.